# Como validar um campo de texto com InputVerifier?

Tags: java, swing, validação

Normalmente quando preciso validar um campo de texto sem utilizar eventos de ação, utilizo eventos de foco, como os disponíveis pela interface [`FocusListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html).

Neste exemplo, eu verifico se o campo foi preenchido ao perder o foco, e retorno o foco pra ele, com uma borda vermelha, caso não tenha sido preenchido:

```
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){

    Border originalBorder;

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){

        JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();

        if(comp.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            originalBorder = originalBorder == null ? comp.getBorder() : originalBorder;
            comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));
            comp.requestFocus();
    } else {
            if(originalBorder != null) {
                input.setBorder(originalBorder);
                originalBorder = null;
            }
        }
});
```

Porém, descobri que a API swing possui a classe [**InputVerifier**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), que me permite fazer a mesma coisa sem ter que gastar listeners de foco, que podem ser úteis para outros recursos.

Como funciona esta classe `InputVerifier` e como a utilizo para garantir que um campo seja preenchido antes de perder o foco, como no exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objetivo da classe `InputVerifier` é permitir o controle da navegação entre componentes de texto através do foco, onde é possível restringir a mudança de campo caso os valores preenchidos neste não atendam a determinado critério definidos no programa.

A classe possui dois métodos abstratos:

- `public abstract boolean verify(JComponent input){}` - este método é quem deve verificar se a informação digitada no campo é válida ou não, através do retorno de um valor `boolean`. Nele não se deve retornar caixas de diálogo ou equivalentes para exibir ao usuário que a entrada do campo é inválida.
- `public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input){}` - este método chama o `verify` para validar o campo. Ele é invocado quando o usuário tenta mudar o foco do componente a ser validado para outro na mesma janela. Seu retorno é que define se o foco poderá ou não ser alterado, por isso, ele pode ser usado para retornar mensagens na tela, como caixas de diálogo.

Partindo do exemplo proposto, basta configurar um novo `InputVerifier` para o campo, passando a validação do `focusLost` para o método `verify()`, e conforme seu retorno, aplicar as alterações no campo através do método `shouldYieldFocus()` afim de alertar quanto ao seu preenchimento:

```
textField.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {

    Border originalBorder;

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {

        JTextField comp = (JTextField) input;
        return !comp.getText().trim().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {

        boolean isValid = verify(input);

        if (!isValid) {
            originalBorder = originalBorder == null ? input.getBorder() : originalBorder;
            input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));
        } else {
            if(originalBorder != null) {
                input.setBorder(originalBorder);
                originalBorder = null;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
});
```

Aplicando ao campo, daria  resultado semelhante ao seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Obs.**: essa validação só vale para navegação através de foco, seja clicando em outros componentes com o mouse ou através da tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd>, mas ela não impede que um formulário seja submetido seja através de um *ActionListener* de um botão ou de outra forma.