# Definir textos a JLabels dinamicamente conforme validação de campos de texto

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Eu tentei adicionar um `label` para cada componente obrigatório da minha tela que esteja vazio (campo 01 e campo 02), então eu criei uma lista de `labels` com a quantidade correspondente de campos/componentes. Porém, as tentativas que eu fiz para que ele "set" as mensagens correspondentes de cada `label` (com os nomes de cada campo) não funcionam adequadamente.

No exemplo eu usei apenas 3 campos do tipo `JTextField`, porém, a ideia, é que a quantidade de campos possa variar.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AdicionaCmp extends JFrame {

    private MeuJTextField jTextField1 = new MeuJTextField(true, "Campo 01");
    private MeuJTextField jTextField2 = new MeuJTextField(true, "Campo 02");
    private MeuJTextField jTextField3 = new MeuJTextField(false, "Campo 03");
    private JButton jButton = new JButton("Validar");
    //private JLabel labelInferior = new JLabel();
    private Font fonte = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10);

    private List<JLabel> listLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<JComponent> listComponentes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(AdicionaCmp::new);
    }

    public AdicionaCmp() {
        add(montaTela());
        //setSize(600, 350);
        pack();

        setVisible(true);
        actionButton();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent montaTela() {
        JPanel painelPrincipal = new JPanel();

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adicionaComponente(1, 1, 1, 1, painel, painelPrincipal);
        adicionaComponente(1, 1, 1, 2, jTextField1, painel);
        adicionaComponente(2, 1, 1, 2, jTextField2, painel);
        adicionaComponente(3, 1, 1, 2, jTextField3, painel);
        adicionaComponente(4, 1, 1, 1, jButton, painel);
        return painelPrincipal;
    }

    public void adicionaComponente(int linha, int coluna, int linhas, int colunas, JComponent componente, JPanel painel) {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = linha;
        gbc.gridx = coluna;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JPanel painelInterno = new JPanel();
        painelInterno.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel rotulo = new JLabel();

        if (componente instanceof MeuJTextField) {
            rotulo = new JLabel(((MeuJTextField) componente).getNome());
        }

        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        painelInterno.add(rotulo, gbc1);

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = (GridBagConstraints) gbc1.clone();
        gbc2.gridx = 2;
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc2.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Especifica que esse componente é o último componente em sua coluna ou linha.
        painelInterno.add(componente, gbc2);

        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = (GridBagConstraints) gbc1.clone();
        gbc3.gridx = 2;
        gbc3.gridy = 2;

        listComponentes.add(componente);

        if ((componente instanceof MeuJTextField) && (((MeuJTextField) componente).eObrigatorio())) {

            JLabel labelInferior = new JLabel();

            for (int i = 0; i < listComponentes.size(); i++) {
                labelInferior = new JLabel();
                painelInterno.add(labelInferior, gbc3);
                setMessage(listLabel, ((MeuJTextField) componente).getNome());
                //listLabel.add(labelInferior);
            }
            listLabel.add(labelInferior);
        }

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridheight = linhas;
        gbc.gridwidth = colunas;
        painel.add(painelInterno, gbc);
    }

    private void actionButton() {
        jButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            validaComponentes();
        });
    }

    private void setMessage(List<JLabel> listLabel, String message) {
        for (JLabel labels : listLabel) {
            labels.setFont(fonte);
            labels.setForeground(new Color(255, 21, 8));
            labels.setText(message);
        }
        pack();
    }

    private boolean validaComponentes() {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] allFields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : allFields) {
            if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object fieldValue = field.get(this);
                    if (fieldValue instanceof MeuJTextField) {
                        if (((MeuJTextField) fieldValue).isEmpty()) {
                            setMessage(listLabel, "O " + ((MeuJTextField) fieldValue).getNome() + " não pode ser vazio !");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    class MeuJTextField extends JTextField implements MeuComponente {

        private boolean eObrigatorio;
        private String nome;

        public MeuJTextField(boolean eObrigatorio, String nome) {
            this.eObrigatorio = eObrigatorio;
            this.nome = nome;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
        }

        @Override
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return getText().trim().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean eObrigatorio() {
            return eObrigatorio;
        }
    }

    public interface MeuComponente {

        public String getNome();

        public boolean eObrigatorio();
    }
}
```

Comment: Com quantos campos você pretente fazer isso? Se for só com 3, é simples. Por isso que é importante fornecer o contexto completo no mcve.

Comment: @Articuno eu estava tentando fazer de um jeito que não fosse fixo, poderia variar .

Comment: Sugestão: edite a pergunta e adicione todas as informações já faladas aqui, porque nela você não diz nada de que o método não seja fixo pra apenas 3 elementos

Comment: @Articuno adicionei mais uma descrição

Comment: Posso sugerir uma alternativa minha de como fazer isso? Tô achando seu código muito bagunçado e cheio de coisas desnecessárias e/ou redundantes. Simplesmente não estou conseguindo nem aplicar minha ideia em cima dele.

Comment: @Articuno pode sim, toda ajuda é bem - vinda

Comment: Precisa mesmo usar recursividade?

Comment: @Articuno faz o seu exemplo, eu tento adaptar conforme a necessidade, você me fornecendo a base, já sera de grande ajuda !

Comment: Uma duvida, porque está adicionando JLabel de rotulo vazia quando não é um campo de texto?

Comment: @Articuno eu não ia colocar pra radioButton, mais acho que tirei do código ai, pra não poluir mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme questionado nos comentários, esta resposta é uma forma alternativa ao que você já fez, que torna o código mais organizado e mais legível:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ValidarCamposComLabelTest  extends JFrame{

    private List<MeuJTextField> fields =  new ArrayList<>();
    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    private JButton jButton = new JButton("Validar");

    private Font fonte = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(ValidarCamposComLabelTest::new);
    }

    public ValidarCamposComLabelTest() {

        JPanel painelPrincipal = new JPanel();

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        fields.add(new MeuJTextField(true, "Campo 01"));
        fields.add(new MeuJTextField(true, "Campo 02"));
        fields.add(new MeuJTextField(true, "Campo 03"));

        int linhaAtual = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++, linhaAtual++) {
            adicionaComponente(linhaAtual, 1, 1, 1, new JLabel(fields.get(i).getNome()), painel);
            adicionaComponente(linhaAtual, 2, 1, 2, fields.get(i), painel);

            if(fields.get(i).eObrigatorio()) {

                JLabel label = new JLabel("");
                label.setFont(fonte);
                label.setForeground(new Color(255, 21, 8));
                adicionaComponente(++linhaAtual, 2, 1, 1, label, painel);
                labels.add(label);
            } 
        }


        adicionaComponente(++linhaAtual, 1, 1, 1, jButton, painel);
        jButton.addActionListener(e -> validaComponentes());

        painelPrincipal.add(painel);
        add(painelPrincipal);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private boolean validaComponentes() {
        boolean retorno = true;

        for(int i = 0; i <fields.size(); i++) {
            if(fields.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                labels.get(i).setText(fields.get(i).getNome() +  " não pode ser vazio !");
                retorno = false;
            } else {
                labels.get(i).setText("");
            }
        }
        pack();
        return retorno;
    }

    private void adicionaComponente(int linha, int coluna, int linhas, int colunas, JComponent componente,
            JPanel painel) {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = linha;
        gbc.gridx = coluna;
        gbc.gridheight = linhas;
        gbc.gridwidth = colunas;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);        
        painel.add(componente, gbc);

    }

    class MeuJTextField extends JTextField implements MeuComponente {

        private boolean eObrigatorio;
        private String nome;

        public MeuJTextField(boolean eObrigatorio, String nome) {
            this.eObrigatorio = eObrigatorio;
            this.nome = nome;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
        }

        @Override
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return getText().trim().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean eObrigatorio() {
            return eObrigatorio;
        }
    }

    public interface MeuComponente {

        public String getNome();

        public boolean eObrigatorio();
    }
}
```

## Mudanças que fiz:

- criei listas de campo(`fields`) e outra pra seus respectivos labels, e adicionei estes conforme a quantidade de campos;
- a variável `linhaAtual` foi criada para poder termos controle da adição dos componentes adicionados na variável `painel`;
- ao adicionar um label referente ao aviso de preenchimento de um campo de texto, é feito um [pré-incremento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243108/28595) na `linhaAtual` para que este componente seja adicionado na linha abaixo do campo de texto;
- o método `adicionaComponente()` foi abstraido, de forma que ele agora pode ser usado para adicionar qualquer componente a qualquer painel da sua tela que tenha um `GridBagLayout` como seu layout, respeitando os valores passados para o `GridBagConstraints`;
- o método `validaComponentes()` está mais enxuto graças as nossas listas de campos de texto e de labels, sem a necessidade de recursividade para varrer os campos. Com um adicional, ele agora também limpa os labels quando o campo passar na validação.

Reitero que apesar de funcional, eu particulamente acho essa forma de abordagem de validação bem ruim, encher a tela de labels pra mostrar mensagem de cada campo não melhora a UX de sua aplicação, muito pelo contrário.

Usando [`InputVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) creio que fique mais amigável, se quiser um exemplo, veja [neste link](https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20551.html) ou [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243918/28595) que fiz aqui no site.

Comment: apenas uma duvida, no caso de adicionar componentes que não sejam obrigatórios, ele vai me retornar um IndexOutOfBoundsException, já que a quantidade de componentes sera maior que a de labels, mesmo que eu coloque para setar apenas nos campos obrigatórios. Por exemplo, mude o campo 02 para não obrigatório.

Comment: @GustavoSantos basta você adicionar apenas campos obrigatórios na lista, uma vez que se um campo não é obrigatório, ele não precisa de um label para valida-lo.

Comment: já é feito assim, ele só adiciona para os obrigatórios, e para validar eu ainda adicionei mais uma condição "if (fields.get(i).isEmpty() && fields.get(i).eObrigatorio()) "

Comment: @GustavoSantos se somente campos obrigatórios é adicionado na lista, não tem como estourar indexoffbound. Confere ai, você deve estar adicionando campos não obrigatórios junto.